# Unable to uninstall node on OS X

Tags: node.js, macos

I have tried the standard

```
brew uninstall node
```

and even went to /usr/local/ to delete the files according to this post: [How do I completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x)

I have received a bunch of error messages but when I type

```
node -v
```

I still get v8.9.4. I can't seem to uninstall it. I'm trying to get to version v6.10.0. Now when I type brew uninstall node it gives the error

```
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/node
```

What more do I need to do?

Comment: Is it installed via nvm?

Answer (score 4):

I recommend figuring out where your node is.
To do this type:

```
 which node
```

If you installed it via homebrew:

```
 brew uninstall node
```

If installed via nvm

You can uninstall a specific version

```
 nvm ls
 nvm uninstall 10.4.1
```

or get rid of nvm and node entirely

```
 rm -rf ~/.nvm
```

and remove all references to NVM in your bash profile.

Comment: Okay, I did that and did

     brew install node@6

it says node is installed when I check with brew but when I try to run node or try

     node -v

I have the error of

     -bash: /Users/alexanderkeefe/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/node: No such file or directory

Comment: Try reinstalling nvm `brew install nvm`, you can use it to manage specific versions of node `nvm install 6.0.0`. You may want to source your profile again as well (close and open your terminal window).

Comment: oh, I think that helped. I also ended up going to this page https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v6.10.0/ to get the installer wizard instead of doing it from the command line. Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem, I definitely recommend NVM to manage your different node versions. Cheers!

Comment: Mine is in `/usr/local/bin/node`

Comment: @Jonny Did you install node via homebrew? If so, you can brew uninstall node. Then I recommend using the nvm package to manage your node versions.

Comment: Don't really remember how/when I installed node  Manually removing files and installing using brew now and I always get this: "Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully". So, I'll try to install using NVM for now.

Comment: Nvm is definitely the way to go. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can check out the Node installation in mac by using the below command. It will show node js version installed in your device.

## node -v

Open the terminal and enter the given below command to know your current directory.

## pwd

Go to your root directory.

## cd /

Then enter into the usr directory by using following command.

## cd usr

Go to locale directory.

## cd local

Enter into include folder by using given below command.

## cd include

Now if you enter the ls command then you’ll see the node folder inside the include folder like given below.

## ls

## node

We have to remove this node folder to completely uninstall the Node js from MacOS.

## sudo rm -R node

Remove node_modules from MacOS

In next step we have to completely remove node_modules from our system.

Follow the steps

Enter the below command to go back to previous folder.

## cd ..

Go to lib directory, hit the below command to enter into the lib directory.

## cd lib

Use the below command to remove the node_modules (NPM) folder.

## sudo rm -R node_modules

Enter the below command to come out from the directory.

## cd ..

Go to bin folder using below command.

## cd bin

Here you also have to delete the node folder to uninstall the Node js completely.

Enter the below command to remove the Node js from MacOS.

## sudo rm -R node

Finally, we’ve successfully uninstalled the Node JS from MacOS, use the given below command to check whether the Node and NPM completely removed from our system.

## node -v

We have completed our task if you are getting below output.

## -bash: node: command not found

Comment: anyway, I've done above, I'm not sure it has been cleared entirely. . why would brew can't manage node?